# How to disable automatic display dimming in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

I normally don't shut down windows and instead put it to hibernate during the night. Sometimes after starting it in the morning, the display brightness adjusts automatically under these conditions

- I open a window with black background, the display lowers the brightness
- I open a window with white background, the display increases the brightness
- I am using a second monitor and this monitor is not affected by this behavior

I read some articles about this, but all these articles talk about settings I don't have in my windows. See the screenshots for reference, where the articles mention a setting like "Help improve battery by optimizing the content shown and brightness" or "Lower screen brightness when using battery saver" or "Enable adaptive brightness".

I also tried to create my own power plan, but there are also no options for this setting available, nor does it have any effect.

I also changed these registry keys:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\Media\Brighten Movie\ProcAmpBrightness -> to 0
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\Media\Darken Movie\ProcAmpBrightness -> to 0

Although I don't know if the registry changes will prevent the problem in the future, since I have to restart for these changes to apply and the issue only arises sometimes.

I have Windows 10 Home, 22H2.

The only option I have found so far to deactivate this "feature", is to restart Windows.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In Windows 10, in Settings, System, Power and Sleep, set the monitor sleep to Never.  See if that helps.  I have a Windows 10 Virtual Machine set this way and the screen stays on.

Comment: Try to disable in *Settings > Personalization > Dynamic lighting* both "Use Dynamic Lighting on my devices" and "Compatible apps in the foreground always control lighting".

Comment: @John thanks but I had tried that already, without success

Comment: @harrymc thanks but I don't see the option "Dynamic lightning" in Personalization nor can I find this option with the search.

Comment: If you have tried the above without success, you likely need to back up and reinstall Windows.  First (and to see if it works) try DISM and SFC (initial Windows Repairs):    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: "Dynamic lighting" is new to Windows 11. Might be worth upgrading - Windows 10 has only one more year of life.

Comment: @harrymc thanks, when I got Windows 11 on my new computer and it eat up 1/3 of my 32GB ram, I decided to go back to my fully backed up Windows 10. So I will stick with Windows 10 as long as possible.

Comment: @John thanks, but in this case, restarting Windows sometimes when it happens is definitely the less time consuming task.

Comment: In Windows 10, if you haven't tried yet : *Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings > Display > Enable adaptive brightness* set to Off.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, but this option does not exist in my windows 10.

Comment: It might not be supported by your display driver.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are describing is called "Adaptive contrast" (as opposed to "Adaptive brightness", which instead reacts to environmental light, on PCs equipped with a light sensor).
Googling for "Disable adaptive contrast Windows 10" brings up solutions involving changes to the Windows registry (see e.g. [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/adczt5/disable_intel_dpst_updated_to_work_for_all_devices/?rdt=65314)).

Apparently behavior has changed over the years and applying those steps exactly as they are described might be not working any more.

Here is how I solved this problem today on my laptop:

- Change registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\FeatureTestControl` to value `9250` (hex)
- Add registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001\FeatureTestControl` with type `DWORD` and value `9250` (hex)

Please note that in my case the original value was not 9240, as stated on the page I linked. However, using value 9250 fixed the problem.

By comparing the linked page and what I had to do, I would suggest this general procedure:

- Change registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\FeatureTestControl` to value `9250` (hex)
- Do the same for all keys `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\000x\FeatureTestControl`
- If you have more `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\000x` under which a FeatureTestControl key is not present, add it and assign value `9250` (hex).

In my case, I had a 0000 group with FeatureTestControl defined with a different value, and a 0001 group where it was not defined.
The only way to solve the problem was to have it both in 0000 and 0001 with the 9250 value.
Changing the value only in 0000 did not solve the problem, and adding the key in 0001 without changing its value also in 0000 also did not solve the problem.

I hope this helps.